# Emojis not working in Windows 10

Tags: fonts, emoji

I use the `win+.` to insert emojis into Visual Studio Code and Windows Terminal, However they don't seem to [work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itxCd.png), instead they show up as "?", The strange bit in this is how I can paste the emojis I copied from the web just fine, But its just the Emoji Panel which doesn't seem to work, I haven't messed around with my font settings, and I use `Cascadia Code PL` as my font in VsCode and Windows Terminal

Edit to add - This problem is strange, in [notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH8vs.png), the emojis show up in a monochrome color, while in VsCode they show up as "?" same goes for Windows Terminal, both of these should support emojis but this problem is still there

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! What happened when you press Win+;

Comment: Hey, when I press ```win+;``` the emoji menu pops up just fine, its just that when I click the emojis, they show up as a "?"

Comment: When the emoji's are inserted, they are inserted in the wrong way as unicode and that is why they get translated and show up as a ?. It may also be that the font itself does not have support for the unicode. You can see if changing the font to ludica console fixes it.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either, still shows up as a "?", I also tried ```Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace, 'Segoe UI Emoji'``` this, but to no avail

Comment: Does the issue only occur with VsCode and Windows Terminal? Check if the issue also occurs with other apps for example Wordpad or Ms Word.

Comment: I have the same issue, sometimes I have to copy them from the web, they work in the terminal , but sometimes with extra spaces before or after and when I delete them they change to diamonds.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use emojis inside vscode you have another option for using emojis in your code.

Hold **`Ctrl`** + **`Shift`** and press **`I`**

[image]

**Then the emoji panel comes**

[image]

Now you can add life to your code, and may it'll fill your career with the same life.